# I was reading a question where it asked if astronauts on space shuttle lost weight would the spacecraft velocity increase? (Assuming closed system)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, mass, velocity, moment-of-inertia

So a lot of the answers had to do with conservation of momentum and the method in which the mass was lost.

Also how a shuttle in orbit speed has nothing to do with mass as its velocity has more to do with inertia and the orbit itself.

Basically this relates to the Apollo 14 feather / hammer

But what about on Earth? Say you’re in a car going x Speed & then throw out (hypothetically) 500 kg - would your speed increase as a result? Being that no other force acting on you?

Ps - I’m new here and physics so please disregard my naivety

Comment: *Conservation of Momentum NOT Conversation 

Comment: I the title of your post did you mean "if the astronauts . . . lost **mass**" rather than "if the astronauts . . . lost **weight**"?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it is easy to see that the shape and velocity of an orbit do not depend on the mass of the orbiting object. Astronauts on the ISS regularly perform EVAs (“spacewalks”) outside of the ISS. During an EVA an astronaut is in the same orbit as the ISS - they appear to be floating in space alongside the ISS. If orbital characteristics depended on mass then the an astronaut on an EVA would fly away from the ISS as soon as they left the airlock, since they and the ISS have such different masses.

As regards your second question about the car, the speed of a car is determined by a balance between the power delivered by its engine, the drag due to air resistance, and other sources of friction. I don’t think any of these will be significantly affected by the mass of the car. So lowering a car’s mass will not affect its speed (although a lower mass will increase the car’s maximum acceleration).